# Installing python34-devel on CentOS does not solve unable to execute 'gcc' error

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, virtualenv, centos7, pipenv

Running on CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
with - Linux version 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC)

```
 Virtualenv location: /mypath/to/project
    + pipenv install -r requirements.txt
    Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfile…
    Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (767e9d)…
    An error occurred while installing lz4==0.11.1! Will try again.
    Installing initially–failed dependencies…
    Collecting lz4==0.11.1 
      Using cached lz4-0.11.1.tar.gz
    Building wheels for collected packages: lz4
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lz4: started
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lz4: finished with status 'error'
      Complete output from command my/project/path/bin/python3.4m -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-74k3sh5f/lz4/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp1swmfp_jpip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lz4
      copying lz4/deprecated.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lz4
      copying lz4/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lz4
      copying lz4/lz4version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lz4
      copying lz4/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lz4
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lz4/block
      copying lz4/block/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lz4/block
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lz4/frame
      copying lz4/frame/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lz4/frame
      running build_ext
      building 'lz4._version' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/lz4
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/lz4libs
      gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Ilz4libs -Ipy3c -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c lz4/_version.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/lz4/_version.o -O3 -Wall -Wundef
      unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Tried to install - python34-devel package but it didnt help

Comment: Install gcc, the installer is trying to compile stuff

Comment: @ geckos I am using Puppet to install packages and below code solved the error, as it comes as $ yum search gcc
package { 'gcc':
      ensure => 'installed',
    }

Comment: I had never used puppet, so the above comment helps you!?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Puppet to install packages and below code solved the error, as it comes as

```
$ yum search gcc package { 'gcc': ensure => 'installed', }
```

– vpd